# Awesomium 1.7.5.1, WinForms, WebControl obj.ExecuteJavascript

Tags: winforms, awesomium, web-control

I want to insert html code into existing html code.
But I do not see the result. Here is the code C #:

1) Program.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        wUI.DocumentReady += wUI_DocumentReady;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code here ?           
    }

    void wUI_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        wUI.LoadHTML("<html><body>sadasdsad</body></html>");
        HtmlManager html = HtmlManager.Instance;
        string[] placeholders = { "asset://customdatastore/path/to/any", "type-button", "no-action", "Example link" };
        html.Add("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"{1}\" id=\"{2}\">{3}</a>", placeholders);
        html.InnerCode(html.Code, wUI, "body");
        wUI.Refresh();
    }
}
```

2) HtmlManager.cs

```
public sealed class HtmlManager
{
    private static readonly Lazy<HtmlManager> InstanceField = new Lazy<HtmlManager>(() => new HtmlManager());
    private StringBuilder _stringBuilder = null;
    public string Code { get { return _stringBuilder.ToString(); } }  

    private HtmlManager() 
    {
        if (_stringBuilder != null)
            _stringBuilder.Clear();
        _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public static HtmlManager Instance { get { return InstanceField.Value; } }

    public void Add(string row, string[] placeholders = null)
    {
        if (placeholders != null)
            _stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format(row, placeholders));
        _stringBuilder.AppendLine(row);
    }

    public void InnerCode(string code, object sender, string afterTag = "html")
    {
        Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl ui = (Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl)sender;
        ui.ExecuteJavascript(string.Format("document.getElementsByTagName({0})[0].innerHTML({1})", afterTag, code));            
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _stringBuilder.Clear();
    }
}
```

The event (DocumentReady) does not happen, I do not believe, maybe I'm wrong somewhere?

UP: I try do it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wUI.LoadHTML("<html><body>sadasdsad</body></html>");       
    }

    void wUI_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlManager html = HtmlManager.Instance;
        string[] placeholders = { "asset://customdatastore/path/to/any", "type-button", "no-action", "Example link" };
        html.Add("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"{1}\" id=\"{2}\">{3}</a>", placeholders);

        wUI.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML(\"sometext\")");  

        //html.InnerCode(html.Code, wUI, "body");
        //wUI.Refresh();
    }
```

No result

UP 2:

```
public void Add(string row, string[] placeholders = null)
    {
        if (placeholders != null)
            _stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format(row, placeholders));
        if (placeholders == null)
            _stringBuilder.AppendLine(row);
    }
```

UP 3:

Work with:

```
wUI.Source = new Uri(@"http://google.com");
```

in Form1_Load

Comment: wUI.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML(\"sometext\")"); of course

Comment: Hah, guys. It's worked, see UP 3 section in post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LoadHtml` method, but only after document is fully loaded (don't confuse with `DocumentReadyState.Ready`) It works for me at least:

```
    private void WebControl_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ReadyState != DocumentReadyState.Loaded) return;


    }
```

But as an initialisation, you should use `Source` property, like you wrote in your third update